# GitHub система работы в команде

Tags: git, github

Всем привет подскажите универсальную систему для работы с репозиторием на GitHub.

Условно: Может ли такая система работать корректно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите насколько сложно будет решать конфликты если будут изменены одинаковые файлы, может где есть хороший гайд о том как это просиходит?

А лучше лучше, конечно, может у кого то из вас есть реальные схемы из вашей практики. По типу 'Мы в команде делаем так: Я делаю клон, делаю ветку для изменений, потом делаю ветку для PR..'

Comment: Если вы работаете условно в команде из 2 человек, почему не сделать себе по отдельной ветке и пушить себе свои изменения без конфликтов? А потом просто слиять ветки через git merge? Просто я не вижу особого смысла в такой схеме, вы создаете новую ветку, но все равно работаете оба на одной ветке

Comment: @Listopad02 Типа у каждого своя ветка? Сделанная из mater? Если Саша и Таня сделают изменения в одном и том же файле и откроют новые PR с вливанием в master то конфликта не будет?

Comment: @MaxWatson пусть не делают изменения в одном и том же файле (не работают одновременно над одной и той же частью проекта), тогда конфликтов не будет. Ну либо договариваются, когда нужно что-то общее поправить, и аккуратно разрешать конфликты. Слияние при PR никак от конфликтов не спасает. В целом - не одна ветка на человека, а одна ветка на фичу.

Comment: Конфликт - это не конец света, если ветки не слишком сильно разошлись, решаются легко. Если сильно разошлись - то проблема. Поэтому нужно периодически мержить к себе в ветку из мастера, ну и перед PR тоже мержить, разрешить все конфликты (если они будут), потом уже делать пулл реквест.

Comment: "делаю ветку для изменений, потом делаю ветку для PR.." - вот это не понятно зачем. Просто делаете ветку для фичи, в ней работаете, потом из не же делаете PR.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!